# Why join is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to pick result from store procedure, it works almost but problem is that it doesn't pick BusNo, which exists in Transport.Buses table and is foreign in dbo.Tickets as Bus_No

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportConductorBusWiseTransactions] 
@FromDate date,
@ToDate date
AS
    BEGIN   
        with myquery ([DateTime],ConductorName,BusNo,amount,Quantity) 
        as
        (
            select  Convert(varchar(20),serverdatetime,101) 'DateTime',b.BusNo,c.Name,T.amount,1 'Quantity'
                 from tickets T join transport.Conductors c on c.Conductorid = T.Conductor_ID
                 join transport.buses b on b.BusID= T.Bus_ID
            WHERE CONVERT(DATE,T.ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
        )
        select *, 10 * c.[10Quantity] '10Amount',20 * c.[20Quantity] '20Amount',30 * c.[30Quantity] '30Amount',((10 * c.[10Quantity])+(20 * c.[20Quantity])+(30 * c.[30Quantity]))'GrandTotal' from (
        SELECT DateTime,ConductorName,BusNo,[10] AS '10Quantity', [20] AS '20Quantity', [30] AS '30Quantity'
        FROM 
        (SELECT [DateTime], ConductorName,BusNo, amount,quantity
        FROM myquery) p
        PIVOT
        (
        COUNT ([Quantity])
        FOR [Amount] IN
        ( [10], [20], [30])
        ) AS pvt
        ) as c
    END
```

I can't adjust my busNo in it, 
Note: each Bus is associated with Conductor and both exists in Tickets table, i am trying to display total transaction by conductor in each bus he has been associated i.e. tickets issued etc but problem is that it doesn't pick BusNo

Comment: Am I missing something? Transport.Buses table is not reference in your shown SQL, nor is BusNo?  Want to add more clarification?

Comment: i tried but failed, so i posted the question,

Comment: Tried what? Failed how? Errors? Miss calculations? You are basically asking us to write the procedure for you.

Comment: wait , i am posting what i tried rightnow

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the desired output vs actual output and what is the current information in your tables?

Comment: Add the sample data for your tables and expected output that you need. That will help us understand what exactly you want.

Comment: it shows ConductorNames in BusNo field but i am trying to pick busNo

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportConductorBusWiseTransactions]  '03-10-2015','03-13-2015'
@FromDate date,
@ToDate date
AS
    BEGIN   
        with myquery ([DateTime],ConductorName,BusNo,amount,Quantity) 
        as
        (
            select  Convert(varchar(20),serverdatetime,101) 'DateTime',c.Name,b.BusNo,T.amount,1 'Quantity'
                 from tickets T join transport.Conductors c on c.Conductorid = T.Conductor_ID
                 join transport.buses b on b.BusID= T.Bus_ID
            WHERE CONVERT(DATE,T.ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
        )
        select *, 10 * c.[10Quantity] '10Amount',20 * c.[20Quantity] '20Amount',30 * c.[30Quantity] '30Amount',((10 * c.[10Quantity])+(20 * c.[20Quantity])+(30 * c.[30Quantity]))'GrandTotal' from (
        SELECT DateTime,ConductorName,BusNo,[10] AS '10Quantity', [20] AS '20Quantity', [30] AS '30Quantity'
        FROM 
        (SELECT [DateTime], ConductorName,BusNo, amount,quantity
        FROM myquery) p
        PIVOT
        (
        COUNT ([Quantity])
        FOR [Amount] IN
        ( [10], [20], [30])
        ) AS pvt
        ) as c
    END
```